# Python linkage to SQL databases

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, database

I've had a fairly good look on the web for an answer to this question, but I've tended to find that people assume more knowledge of databases than I currently have.  I'm sorry if this is a rookie question - I've always been aware of databases and their advantages, but never actually had to work with them.

I have a requirement for a series of Python applications to read and write to a single SQL database.

My original plan was to create the database using SQLServer (at least while experimenting) and then access it via Python.  However, when I came to look at relevant Python packages (sqlite3, sqlalchemy, etc), they appear to create and maintain the database completely through Python.

This is absolutely fine, but will those Python-created-databases be fully compatible with non-Python tools and processes?  We will need to read data from C# as well.

As a secondary question, I like the look of sqlalchemy, but has it gone mainstream?

Comment: Although I would consider creating and maintaining databases in Python bad practice ( at least for MySQL and SQL Server), these databases will be fully compatible with non-Python tools and processes as they created with the same SQL code. Regarding SQLAlchemy, this is used by several major companies and I have never experienced any problems with it, other than performance for large inserts.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jaco - that's what I needed to know.  Do you fancy posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would consider creating and maintaining databases in Python bad practice ( at least for MySQL and SQL Server), these databases will be fully compatible with non-Python tools and processes as they are created with the same SQL code. Regarding SQLAlchemy, this is used by several major companies and I have never experienced any problems with it, other than slow performance for large inserts.

Comment: Thanks, @Jaco.  One clarification: why would you consider getting Python to create the database bad practice?